# scanner.skip(pattern) gives Exception for String and File but not for System.in

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("x.txt"); //x.txt has "xxx" 
        String x = "xxx";
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(x);
        s.skip("g");
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
    }
}
```

In case of a reading from File or String, `java.util.NoSuchElementException` gets thrown if pattern does not match at the current cursor position.

But in case of `System.in` no Exception is thrown if pattern does not match at the current cursor position. Instead the cursor just keeps skipping input. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of File and String your input is terminated, whereas System.in continually provides data to Scanner if you type more characters to the console.

You can see same result with System.in if it is terminated. This example provides a fixed set of values for System.in to the java process so that end of the stream is read and you'll get `java.util.NoSuchElementException`:

```
echo xxx | java -cp your.jar Main
```

Comment: Just to add IMO core aspect. `skip` doesn't just handle single token like for instance `next` method. `skip` method can handle entire text which is why in case regex doesn't match *currently* Scanner will not assume that it will not match at all. Instead it will want to be sure by waiting for entire data (until source of data will end/will be closed) to make the decision. Although theoretically it could be optimized for instance when regex has obvious maximal length like `skip("abc")` such optimization was not included in regex/skip method.